# Web scraping with Anaconda and Python 3.65

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, anaconda

I'm not a programmer, but I'm trying to teach myself Python so that I can pull data off various sites for projects that I'm working on. I'm using "Automate the Boring Stuff" and I'm having trouble getting the examples to work with one of the pages I'm trying to pull data from.

I'm using Anaconda as my prompt with Python 3.65. Here's what I've done:

Step 1: create the beautiful soup object

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('https://www.almanac.com/weather/history/zipcode/02111/2017-05-15')
res.raise_for_status()
weatherTest = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
type(weatherTest)
```

This works, and returns the result

```
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
```

I've made the assumption that the "noStarchSoup" that was in the original text (in place of weatherTest here) is a name the author gave to the object that I can rename to something more relevant to me. If that's not accurate, please let me know.

Step 2: pull an element out of the html

Here's where I get stuck. The author had just mentioned how to pull a page down into a file (which I would prefer not to do, I want to use the bs4 object), but then is using that file as his source for the html data. The exampleFile was his downloaded file.

```
import bs4
exampleFile = open('https://www.almanac.com/weather/history/zipcode/02111/2017-05-15')
```

I've tried using weatherTest in place of exampleFile, I've tried running the whole thing with the original object name (noStarchSoup), I've even tried it with exampleFile, even though I haven't downloaded the file.

What I get is

> "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
>   'https://www.almanac.com/weather/history/zipcode/02111/2017-05-15'

The next step is to tell it what element to pull but I'm trying to fix this error first and kind of spinning my wheels here.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the element you're trying to scrape with either the `find` or `find_all` methods of the BeautifulSoup object you created (aka `weatherTest`)? You don't need to save the page to a file to do this. Also you're correct that `weatherTest` is simply a variable name that you can modify without altering the functionality.

Comment: check the Beautiful Soup documentation at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't resist here!

I found this page during my search but this answer didn't quite help... try this code :)

Step 1: download Anaconda 3.0+

Step 2: (function)

```
# Import Libraries
import bs4 
import requests

def import_high_short_tickers(market_type):
    if market_type == 'NADAQ':
        page = requests.get('https://www.highshortinterest.com/nasdaq/')
    elif market_type == 'NYSE':
        page = requests.get('https://www.highshortinterest.com/nyse/')
    else:
        logger.error("Invalid market_type: " + market_type)
        return None

    # Parse the HTML Page
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    # Grab only table elements
    all_soup = soup.find_all('table')

    # Get what you want from table elements!
    for element in all_soup:        
        listing = str(element)

        if 'https://finance.yahoo.com/' in listing:   

            # Stuff the results in a pandas data frame (if your not using these you should)
            data = pd.read_html(listing)

    return data
```

Yes Yes its very crude but don't hate!
Cheers!